# Use shortcut key as Access key in a web page

Tags: javascript, html

I tried to use accesskey on webpages, it works fine.

```
<a href="http://localhost/" accesskey="h">HTML5</a><br>
or
document.getElementById("myAnchor").accessKey = "w";
```

But this requires another key to be pressed for accessing the key 'h' i.e. 'alt+h' in chrome browser.
How to use the access key as a combination with another key like 'ctrl+h' or 'ctrl+d' like that.

Can anyone help me to plot it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The accesskey is browser specific and you can not change it:

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_accesskey.asp

If you want to have such combinations you must use javascript

something like:

```
$('body').keydown(function(e){
    if(e.shiftKey&&e.ctrlKey){
        ///something in here
    }
});
```

If you want to use accesskey for many elements you can create your own plugin like:

```
<a href="http://localhost/" data-accesskey="shift+h">HTML5</a>

$('body').on('keydown','[data-accesskey]',function(e){
   var keys = $(this).data('accesskey').split('+');
   var shift = ($.inArray('shift',keys)>=1?true:false);
   var ctrl= ($.inArray('ctrl',keys)>=1?true:false);
if(e.ctrlKey||!ctrl){
    if(e.shiftKey||!shift){
         // now in here you can bind what ever function you want to it
    }
}
});
```

Comment: but when im using gmail, certain combination of keys are used to do particular action. how to achieve it?for example: 'ctrl+shift+k' to access the onscreen keyboard, like that.

Comment: they are done using javascript and not just using the html accesskey

Comment: in this link http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_accesskey.asp they are doing the same thing as they did in html. but how to use combination of keys using js?

Comment: have a look at my answer